# Can we say that $f_n (x) \to f(x),$ as $n \to \infty$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

> Let $\{f_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ and $f$ be integrable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1} f_n (x)\ dx \to \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\ dx\ \text {as}\ n \to \infty.$$

> Does it imply that $f_n (x) \to f(x),$ as $n \to \infty$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]\ $?

Comment: I google it just now and find typewriter sequence. A typewriter sequence of functions has the nice property that their integral converges to $0$ i.e. $L^1$-norm of such sequence of functions converges to $0$ but the functions do not converge to $0$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't hold.  Integrals are aggregates, and you therefore lose information about the functions by integrating; saying that two curves have similar area under them hardly means the curves themselves are similar.

For instance: take $f(x)=1$, and take $f_n(x)=2x$ for all $n$.

Then $\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=1$ for all $n$, but clearly $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: What if it was given that $\displaystyle {\int_{0}^{1} \left \lvert f_n (x) - f(x) \right \rvert\ dx \to 0},$ as $n \to \infty\ $? Does the same counter-example hold? I don't think so. Then the limit of the above integral evaluates to $\dfrac 1 4 \neq 0.$

Comment: If you require that $\int_0^1\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\,dx\to0$, you can conclude that you have convergence in measure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure. This does not imply that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for almost all $x$, either (for a counterexample, see the above page), but it implies that there is a subsequence with $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$ for almost all $x$.

Comment: @Martin Väth I have commented already that I have found typewriter sequence. But I don't know how to prove that the typewriter sequence doesn't converge for any $x \in [0,1].$ Can you help me proving this? BTW your last remark (after the parentheses) follows from the proof of Riesz-Fischer theorem. Right?

Comment: I did not understand that you know already the typewriter sequence $f_n$. To see that this sequence does not converge for any $x$, just observe that (for fixed $x$), the sequence $f_n(x)$ assumes both values $0$ and $1$ infinitely many often. If you visualize the typewriter sequence geometrically, this oscillaltory behavior is obvious, a formal proof using the definition is a bit harder. For a convergent subsequence, you can use the Riesz-Fischer proof, but there are also proofs using only measure convergence: Let $\sum_{k=1}^\infty mes\{x:\lvert f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)\rvert\,dx>1/k\}<\infty$ ...